# Asynchronus database population

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, windows-phone-8, asynchronous

In my application I am using SOAP service to download CSV files which are used to populate different tables in a Sqlite database. I am using SQLite.Net library to for database operations.

For populating the database I have written methods for each table (because of different schema). Those methods are running synchronously. Inside those methods I am using instance of a synchronous SQL connection.

When I changed my methods from `void` to `async Task` and calling them with `await` I don't know if those methods finished, and when.

My question is what approach should I take to be able to change those operations to asynchronous and how to define events when each methods finishes. I never wrote event before so it would be greatly appreciated if some one could give some sample how to do that.

Comment: Please post some code rather than describing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Task` returned from the asynchronous methods gives you what you need. The `Task` type will notify the calling code when the asynchronous method completes.

The easiest way to take advantage of this is to have the calling code use `await`. For example, if you want to (asynchronously) wait for each table to be populated:

```
await PopulateTable1Async();
await PopulateTable2Async();
await PopulateTable3Async();
```

Alternatively, you may want to populate all tables simultaneously, in which case you can use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(PopulateTable1Async(), PopulateTable2Async(), PopulateTable3Async());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaination, Is there possibility that one async method that calls other async methods (those which populate tables) could finish before they finish ? ex async Test(){ await pupulate1(); await populate2();} is that possible that Test() will finish before populate1 or populate2 ?

Comment: No. You can think of `await` as "asynchronous wait", so the method will not continue until that operation completes.

Comment: Ok I've done 1 test , basicaly on button click I'am downloading file synchronously then when unzipping file and extracting its contetns to db I'm trying to keep track of methods that are called and display it by changing label's text, Label doesn't get updated UI stays responsive and theres no errors, but how can i trigger event when all those methods finish ?

Comment: If you're doing everything *synchronously*, then the UI thread is being blocked and that's why it cannot update.